# Issue with CancellationTokenSource in C#

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to create a helper class for sending some information periodically to backend server.
Attaching the code below.

```
public class HeartBeatService
{
        private CancellationToken _cancellationToken;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

        public void StartHeartBeatService(TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            Task.Run(async () =>
           {
               while (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
               {
                   SendHeartBeatToAzure();
                   try
                   {
                       await Task.Delay(timeSpan, _cancellationToken);
                   }
                   catch
                   {
                       break;
                   }
               }
           });
        }
        public void SuspendHeartBeatService()
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
        }

        private async void SendHeartBeatToAzure()
        {
            var platformService = ServiceLocator.Get<IPlatformService>();
            var location = await platformService?.GetPositionAsync();

            if (!double.IsNaN(location.Item1) && !double.IsNaN(location.Item2))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Triggering Heartbeat with location{location.Item1},{location.Item2}");
                //TODO Invoke heartbeat api call.
            }
        }
    }
```

The code for sending the information to server is working fine.

But there is some issue with **CancellationToken** which is not working/it is not cancelling.
not sure what's wrong with the implementation.

Comment: *Possibly* that you are using `async void` in method `SendHeartBeatToAzure` which should only be used for event driven calls like button click. That should probably be `async Task`. You are also not awaiting the result of `SendHeartBeatToAzure`.

Comment: You shouldn't ever write these "empty" try-catches. What if the next task could solve it.

Comment: First of all, this is not the efficient way of implementing the heart beat service. The efficient way is to use `System.Threading.Timer`. Second, the `CancellationTokenSource` is disposable resource and must be disposed. Third, you need to make `_cancellationToken` local to avoid wrong instance being used in the while loop, if `StartHeartBeatService` is invoked twice. So the reason it may not be cancelled could be due to multiple start invocations on the same instance

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). It is intended for event handlers only.

Comment: I suggest that you mark the fields `_cancellationToken` and `_cancellationTokenSource` as [`readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly#readonly-field-example), to enforce your intention that their values will never be replaced after the object is constructed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the signature of the `SendHeartBeatToAzure` to return a `Task`, so that it can be awaited:

```
private async Task SendHeartBeatToAzure()
```

Then `await` the task returned by the method inside the loop. To achieve a stable and consisted heartbeat, it is a good idea to create the `Task.Delay` task before calling the method:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        var delayTask = Task.Delay(timeSpan, _cancellationToken);
        await SendHeartBeatToAzure();
        await delayTask;
    }
});
```

As a side note, you should probably store the task returned by `Task.Run` as a readonly property of the `HeartBeatService` class, so that the status of the task can be monitored.

Comment: I tried the way you advised. But still the cancellation is not working. Some issue with cancellation logic

Comment: @Sooraj you mean that after you cancel the loop with the method `SuspendHeartBeatService`, the `SendHeartBeatToAzure` keeps been called?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake from my side. Let me test it again.

Comment: What was the mistake?

Comment: I was initialising the class on each button click.. sorry.. silly mistake

Comment: @Sooraj no problem, it happens. :-)